# Powershell - What verb should I use for Undelete

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a PowerShell module.  I've implemented a Delete function using Remove-blah.  Now I need to implement an Undelete function.  It isn't on the approved verb list, as far as I can see.  Is there a convention for verb-usage for Undelete?  If not, what should I use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the ActiveDirectory module, the cmdlet to undelete a deleted AD object is Restore-AdObject, so I'd think there's an arguable case for adoptiong that convention.

Comment: 'restore' was my first thought, as well.

Comment: That's good enough for me, thanks.  Hadn't come across that one, before.